# Convert Javscript toLocalTimeString HH:MM:SS to HH:MM with AM/PM

Tags: javascript, date, time

I have two different time strings `time1 = 6:00 AM` and `time2 = 1:15:04 AM`. I need to compare these two strings. I want to convert `time2` to `1:00 AM` so that it is in same format than `time1`. How can I convert HH:MM:SS to HH:MM? I need to keep AM/PM.

**time1**

```
//input time
var input_time = $('#cleaning_service_time').val();//returns 6:00 AM
```

**time2**

```
//current browser time
var dateToday = new Date(); 
var timeNow = dateToday.toLocaleTimeString('en-US');
```

compare

```
    if(input_time < timeNow){

    alert("You can't book an appointment in the past.");

    }else{

   //appointment booked

    }
```

Comment: You are asking multiple questions: how to reformat a time string and how to compare times as strings. What have you tried?

Comment: @RobG: I don't think I am asking multiple questions here. I'm asking only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest better go with [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) it will simplify a lot of work. Use desired format out of many [available](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) ones for parsing out input string

```js
var input_time = '6:00 AM';
const today = moment(input_time, ['h:mm A']);

var dateToday = new Date(); 
var timeNow = dateToday.toLocaleTimeString('en-US');
var someday = moment(dateToday);

var diff = today.diff(someday, 'minutes');

if(diff < 0){
    alert("You can't book an appointment in the past.");
}else{
   //appointment booked
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```